# I am expecting a sample registration from using react.But no output

Tags: reactjs

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    input: [
      { name: "First Name", type: "text" },
      { name: "Last Name", type: "text" },
      { name: "Age", type: "number" },
      { name: "Email", type: "email" },
    ],
    fs: false,
  };
  render() {
    let decisionMake = (decision) => {
      this.fs = decision;
    };
    return (
      <div className="App-header">
        {" "}
        <p> Do you want to enter your data ? </p>{" "}
        <button onClick={() => decisionMake(true)}> Yes </button>{" "}
        <button onClick={() => decisionMake(false)}> No </button>
        {this.state.fs ? (
          <div>
            {this.state.input.map((input) => {
              return <Input name={input.name} type={input.type} />;
            })}{" "}
          </div>
        ) : null}{" "}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

component is correct(verified).But only displaying the buttons.I neeed to display that sample form while clicking the yes button.But no result is printing after clicking the buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), you're just setting an instance variable `fs`, which React doesn't know anything about.

You'll want

```
let decisionMake = (decision) => {
  this.setState({fs: decision});
};
```

to set `this.state.fs`.